# QT unixtimestamp conversion not print GMT time

Tags: qt, datetime, gmt

I have unixtimestamp `1579106713` which represent `1/15/2020 16:45:13` and I need to convert this time in Qt, I have used the code but getting different value

```
 int unixTimeTmp = 1579106713; // 1/15/2020 16:45:13
 QDateTime timestampq;
 timestampq.setTime_t(unixTimeTmp);
 qDebug() << timestampq.toString();
```

Give the output

```
Wed Jan 15 11:45:13 2020 // expect Wed Jan 15 16:15:33 2020
```

When I checked here https://www.epochconverter.com, I have seen that I have to get the GMT output, but no idea how I can get using Qt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the timespec to `Qt::UTC`.  Like this:

```
int unixTimeTmp = 1579106713; // 1/15/2020 16:45:13
QDateTime timestampq;
timestampq.setTime_t(unixTimeTmp);
timestampq.setTimeSpec(Qt::UTC);
qDebug() << timestampq.toString();
```